# Why is my Java KeyListener not working in this specific case?

Tags: java, keylistener

It doesn't even print the keys to the command prompt.  Thanks in advance.

Here's the class for the keylistener

```
public static class KeyWatch extends KeyAdapter implements KeyListener 
        {
            int x;
            int y;

            public KeyWatch(int x, int y)
            {
                x=this.x;
                y=this.y;
            }

            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
            {
                int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

                if(keyCode==KeyEvent.VK_UP)
                {
                    System.out.println("up");
                    y=y+20;
                }
                if(keyCode==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
                {
                    System.out.println("Down");
                    y=y-20;
                }
                if(keyCode==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
                {
                    System.out.println("Right");
                    x=x+20;
                }
                if(keyCode==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
                {
                    System.out.println("Left");
                    x=x-20;
                }
            }

            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){}

            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){}



        }
```

and here's the call in the window  out of context

```
window.setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
     KeyWatch watcher = new KeyWatch(x, y);

playerlabel = new JLabel(player);
      playerlabel.addKeyListener(watcher);
      playerlabel.setLocation(x, y);
```

### window.add(playerlabel);

anyway the point is to move the Jlabel around the window.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the label get the focus:

```
playerLabel.requestFocus();
```

Call this after the key listener has been added, the label has been added to the view hierarchy and it became visible.